# How to increase quality of FFMpeg debayer?

Tags: ffmpeg

There is a problem with the FFMpeg debayer as it doesn't give enough quality.

The command I use for debayer is :

```
ffmpeg -i %input% -vf format=gray -f rawvideo pipe: | ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format bayer_rggb8 -video_size %video_size% -i pipe: -pix_fmt yuv420p %output_direct_debayer_bmp%
```

and the result is :

[image]

but the needed result is :

[image]

The difference is that the debayer img result obtained with FFMpeg looks like has a blur effect or not enough sharp compared with the `requested` img result as in screenshot 2

After a little research was found out that it is only the one way for debayering with ffmpeg, so the question is there some workarounds?

Comment: Why `-pix_fmt yuv420p`?

Comment: @Gyan it is a format that I need to get as a result, I am not sure that it could be a reason for such a blur effect. Why?

Comment: 420 has reduced chroma resolution, which will result in a softer image. The reason I asked is that BMPs don't store YUV. It will converted to an RGB format.

Comment: @Gyan what is your suggestion?

Comment: Use `-pix_fmt rgb24` instead.

Comment: @Gyan it gives the same result. I think that problem is that the debayer algorithm, not enough efficient...